# Expand absolute parent div to height of relative child

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to animate my ng-view with a slide effect. Therefore I got 3 divs

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
   <div ng-view style="position:absolute">
       <div style="position:relative"> LONG CONTENT </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I´m testing these [effect](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1). The outer `div` needs to be `overflow:hidden` to let my slide effekt work.The inner `div` needs to be `absolute`. If the inner `div` contains some text, the other 2 divs should expand the height according to the very inner `div`. Same like when all `divs` would be relative. How to achieve this?

Like in my example link but with variable height.

EDIT: This is a complete other question then the "possible" duplicate.

Comment: nope. this is the other way around. outer -> relative, inner -> absolute. Please remove the duplicate flag

Comment: On your snippet, the most inner div must be able to stretch its parent. Do you have the CSS and JS?

Comment: I may have clicked on the wrong link. The divs do expand so I think Angular is what's causing you problems. Or are you wanting the hidden div to expand, too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of your contents, you`re making your inner div absolute, so the parents it won’t
have any height. First thing you have to do is define size to your elements and than you can use absolute elements to make your layout.

see the example below, i define a div named .page with min-height:200px, that will be enough to appear your element (.slide), because if you don’t do this, your element(.page) height will be 0, and it will be cut by overflow:hidden.

```html
<style>
  .page {
    background-color: #DDD;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
  }

  .slider{
    position: absolute;  
  }

  .slide{
    position: relative;  
  }
</style>

<div class="page">
   <div class="slider" ng-view>
       <div class="slide"> LONG CONTENT </div>
   </div>
</div>
```